Python script I am trying to solve
I have this challenge I have been trying to solve. Here is the script :
import hashlib

def takingPotion(memory, key):

    result = bytearray(len(memory))
    for i in range(len(memory)):
        result[i] = memory[i] ^ key
    return bytes(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Ryan's memory is all scrambled.
    memory = 'd4e0b9f4fcf4f6ebe0b9f1f8effcb9fbfcfcf7b9faecebfcfdb7b9d0b9ebfcf4fcf4fbfcebb9f7f6eeb7b9daf7dce2fdaaaae9aaebc6a8f7c6e0a9ecebc6f1aaadfde4'

    # The lost recipe is here, but it is a foreign language.
    lostRecipe = 'c5a5e3dcb87d3538b366b24f459c436a'
    
    # Enter the proper potion formula to cure Ryan.
    recipe = input("Enter mental cure recipe: ")

    # Mixing the potion to see if it matches the formula in his head.
    mixRecipe = hashlib.md5(recipe.encode())    

    # Is it the right formula?
    if mixRecipe.hexdigest() == lostRecipe:
        # Extract the ingredients from the formula to get the proper mix.
        ingredient = int((recipe[0] + recipe[1]).encode(), 16)
        isCured = takingPotion(bytes.fromhex(memory), ingredient)
        print (isCured.decode())
    else:
        print ("It didn't work!")

I think it is supposed to be much simpler than trying to crack the MD5 hash in the script. I cannot seem to understand how to resolve this in a simple way.

First solve the challenge of giving your question a meaningful, descriptive name.

If you read the takingPotion function (a simple XOR cipher), you can tell key is a single integer.
Looking at what is passed as the key, ingredient = int((recipe[0] + recipe[1]).encode(), 16), we can tell it's decoded from two hex characters, i.e. its range is 0..255.
You now know there are 256 possible keys to decode Ryan's memory with, and we can easily presume, for a challenge like this, that the output should be human-readable.
You can either use heuristics to figure out which of the 256 possible outputs is the most human-readable, or you can just visually grep (i.e. using your eyeballs) to find the single output that is in English. For fun, let's use heuristics:
scrambled = bytes.fromhex(
    "d4e0b9f4fcf4f6ebe0b9f1f8effcb9fbfcfcf7b9faecebfcfdb7b9d0b9ebfcf4fcf4fbfcebb9f7f6eeb7b9daf7dce2fdaaaae9aaebc6a8f7c6e0a9ecebc6f1aaadfde4",
)


def human_readability_score(text):
    return sum(1 for c in text if c.isalpha() or c == " ")


unscrambled_options = {
    key: bytes(c ^ key for c in scrambled).decode("utf-8", "ignore")
    for key in range(256)
}

unscrambled_scored = sorted(
    unscrambled_options.items(),
    key=lambda pair: human_readability_score(pair[1]),
    reverse=True,
)

print(unscrambled_scored[0])


Thank you very much for your explanation. It makes sense now!
